# Convert javascript links in PDF to real annotations

Tags: java, javascript, pdf, hyperlink, annotations

We are using javascript in PDFs to facilitate the automated creation of Goto page.. etc links, or based on certain keywords.

LIke this: this.pageNum = 2

This works fine, as long the PDF is opened inside a viewer that supports javascript.

I am now looking for a way, preferably i Java, to convert these annotations to real annotations, which will then be usable outside of Acrobat.

I have done quite some research on the net so far (i think. ,) - but couldnt find an approach how to go on with that.

Comment: I asked a similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908906/acrobat-javascript-convert-javascript-page-links-to-real-links

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, links containing JavaScript are real annotations.

Whether it is possible to convert depends a lot on the JavaScripts you attempt to convert. With very simple things like `pageNum = x` you may be able to find a replacement, but you will quickly run out of options, because the number of Actions available is rather limited.

But already a simple construct like setting the value of a document level variable (set in a document-level script):

```
var cameFrom ;
```

in the link or button you use to jump to another page

```
camefrom = this.pageNum ;
```

and have a button/link to jump back to where you came from

```
this.pageNum = camefrom ;
```

will be essentially impossible to solve programmatically.

You will also have to make many assumptions, which may work for your specific files.

Comment: I might have been not clear enough ;) What I want is to take the PDF with javascript annotations and convert them in non-javascript annotations. And this preferably with JAVA for interoperablitly.

Comment: It was absolutely clear enough. You do have a chance of success where there is a "normal" action corresponding to the JavaScript assigned to the annotation. If there is none, you simply can't do it. You can only convert very simplistic JavaScript actions to "normal" action; even that (really very simple) example I showed will fail miserably.

Comment: Where do you want to use Java? PDF/Acrobat does not support Java.

Comment: *What I want is to take the PDF with javascript annotations and convert them in non-javascript annotations.* - what @Max tried to tell you is that there is much more you can do using Javascript than with non-javascript annotations.

Comment: @mkl  i need to post-process these PDFs for extracting the links into XML on a linux server application + in Windows based applications which do not tie into Acrobat - in the next step - that is why i want to use JAVA to achieve that.