# Acrobat JavaScript - convert JavaScript page links to "real links"

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

**The situation:**
I have ~1,000,000 PDF files.  I am using Acrobat JavsScript to search for certain keywords in each of the PDFs, and then give the keyword a link by `setAction("this.pageNum = n")`.  The `pageNum` value, n, is generated by my script, too. The result is that the user can go to page number n directly by clicking the link.

**The problem:**
I do not want the links to trigger JavaScript actions.  Instead, I want to them to be `"real links"`.  Each of the `"real link"` should point to the same page number as the JavaScript action does.  The reason is that I want users to be able to use the links with a PDF reader that does not allow JavaScript (e.g. SumatraPDF or Chrome browser).

- It would be ideal if the solution is implemented in Acrobat
  JavaScript, so that I can integrate into my script. If not possible,
- It would also be great if the solution can be implemented in Python,
  since the problem is part of a larger Python application I am
  developing.
- If still not possible, a solution in any programming
  language will suffice.

**What I have tried:**
I have looked up the entire "JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference".  The Link object does not have a `"go to page reference"` property (unlike, using HTML as an analogy, the `"a"` tag has an `"href"` property).  It seems to me that the Link object only allows `setAction()` method - but please correct me if I am wrong.

**Similar question?**
Someone has asked a similar question, but both the question and answer was rather vague (no offense, please), so I'm asking again.
[Convert javascript links in PDF to real annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173725/convert-javascript-links-in-pdf-to-real-annotations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used a script from this site:

http://try67.blogspot.de/2011/09/convert-javascript-links-to-real-web.html

Its a java tool which does exactly that - if you need a quick solution.

It seems that JAVA will be the approach to interpret the javascript inside the PDF. 
Pythons PDF does

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Do you think there is an open-source solution out there?  I need to customize the tool and preferably migrate it to Python.

Comment: Also, I plan to develop a tool of my own.  It seems, in order to do that, I need to understand the underlying workings of PDF files, and to be able to edit the "source code" of a PDF file. Can you point me to some books/resources that I need?